# Range of dates and go through each date at a certain hour

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-datetime, timedelta

I am trying to iterate through a date range (8/1/19-3/31/20) and go through each date and print a count for hours 4 AM, 5 AM, and 6 AM. However, I'm having some general trouble getting the required dates and iterating. I keep getting various `datetime` and `datetime.timedelta` errors.

Here is the code:

```py
start = datetime.timedelta(2019, 8, 1)
end = datetime.timedelta(2020, 3, 31)
days = (end - start).days + 1
for i in (start + end for n in range(days)):
    for j in range(4, 7):
        print "Hour: ", i
        print ("Residents: ", Checkin.objects.filter(desk__name="Desk", datetime__hour=i.hour(j)).count())
        print("Guests: ", Guest.objects.filter(desk="Desk", datetime__hour=i.hour(j)).count())
```

I am just hoping for the best way to do this, as I am trying to gather this data for someone. The error I'm getting currently from this code is timedelta doesn't have an hour attribute. I'm just hoping for help getting this code functional.

I am filtering `Checkin` and `Guest` by their datetime field, which is:

`datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: @Gabip I'm using `i` which should contain the date and then I'm trying to get the hour from the date and use them both?

Comment: `i` is a timedelta object since it is taken from the generator `(start + end for n in range(days))` - what do you want to achieve here? have one iteration for each date?

Comment: @MrFuppes 3 iterations for each time on each date

Comment: alright, but how do you pass the date (that belongs to each hour) to the methods of your `Checkin` and `Guest` classes/objects? - see [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61526672/10197418)

Comment: @MrFuppes I'm using Django so `Checkin` and `Guest` are models that have a date time field named "date" so I'm using it to filter it each time and get the count

Comment: so what you pass as `datetime__hour` keyword should be of type `datetime.datetime`?

Comment: @MrFuppes actually, I believe the field is **Django's* DateTimeField, so that probably makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```py
beg_date = datetime(2019, 8, 1)
        end_date = datetime(2020, 3, 31)
        residents_in_range = Checkin.objects.filter(desk__name="Robinson Hall", datetime__gte=beg_date, datetime__lte=end_date)
        guests_in_range = Guest.objects.filter(desk__name="Robinson Hall", datetime__gte=beg_date, datetime__lte=end_date)
        rez_by_day = []
        guests_by_day = []
        one_day = timedelta(days=1)
        while beg_date <= end_date:
            rez_by_day.append(residents_in_range.filter(datetime__gte=beg_date, datetime__lt=beg_date+one_day))
            guests_by_day.append(guests_in_range_in_range.filter(datetime__gte=beg_date, datetime__lt=beg_date+one_day))
            beg_date += one_day
        four = []
        five = []
        for day in rez_by_day:
            four.append(day.filter(datetime__hour__gte=4, datetime__hour__lt=5))
            five.append(day.filter(datetime__hour__gte=5, datetime__hour__lt=6))
        for count in four:
            print(count.count())
        for count in five:
            print(count.count())
```

I had it just print the numbers so I could copy and paste into an excel file and I just separated the information in lists further and further reducing and getting the information I want

I tried to fill out the code more but what I did was replace the halls and guests/residents list every time I wanted different data. I didn't do it in one go-around.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31)

# increment the start date until it reaches the end
while start <= end:
    for j in range(4, 7):
        i = start.replace(hour=j) # create the datetime with the desired hour
        print("Hour: ", i)
        print("Residents: ", Checkin.objects.filter(desk__name="Desk", datetime__hour=i).count())
        print("Guests: ", Guest.objects.filter(desk="Desk", datetime__hour=i).count())
    start += datetime.timedelta(days=1) # increment the start date
```

Comment: it seems strange that the objects `Checkin` and `Guest` never get to know the date - for each iteration of the loop, the called method will only receive the same set of hours

Comment: @MrFuppes `i` is passed to `Checkin` and `Guest` and it contains the date and the hour

Answer (score -1):

Trying to keep your initial style on the answer:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31)
days = (end - start).days + 1


for i in range(days):
    my_datetime = start + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    print('Processing date', my_datetime)
    for j in range(4, 7):
        my_datetime_with_hour = my_datetime + datetime.timedelta(hours=j)
        print('\t', 'Hour', my_datetime_with_hour)
        q1 = Checkin.objects.filter(
            desk__name="Desk",
            datetime__hour=my_datetime_with_hour.hour,
            )
        q2 = Guest.objects.filter(
            desk="Desk",
            datetime__hour=my_datetime_with_hour.hour,
            )
        print("Residents:", q1.count())
        print("Guests:", q2.count())
```